MacBook Pro with M1 chip saving GNAT Studio, GCC for Ada 12 substituting a '-' for the '.' in Package.Child naming. Issue with Unix/Darwin and '.'?
MacBook Pro, running GNATStudio  for Ada 12: On attempting to create child packages (as a work around for 'limited with’ problems I have not figured out yet) - reciprocal 'with and use' problems of two mutually dependent packages. GNAT is saving my packageA.child.ads as packageA-child.ads, and then says it can’t find packageA-child.ads, which of course does not exist, the child package being saved with the ‘-’ separator rather than '.' Using an Apple Macbook Pro with  M1 chip, I’m wondering if the (Unix-Darwin Sonoma 14.5) doesn’t like the ‘.’ and saves as ‘

Discovered my error: The actual file is saved with '-' separator: grids-solve.ads; but in Ada code the child package 'solve' is designated and named, grids.solve (the child package) distinct from the actual OS file name. Makes sense, but not explicitly
mentioned in most books or references I have found.Most often file name and Ada name match.
